# Bubble rejection

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to code a command that takes two arguments: the first one is the player to be bubbled, the second one is the radius of the bubble.
It would look like `/bubble <player> <radius>`.

I basically want anyone who walks within that radius to get shot out very far, but I really have no idea how to do this.
The main part I'm stuck on is knowing whether or not someone is within 5 blocks from the victim (using metadata) and how to sort them.

```
package me.Glowhoo.EpicUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.metadata.FixedMetadataValue;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
/*
 * Author =
* Glowhoo
* 
*/
public class Bubble implements CommandExecutor, Listener {
    private Main plugin;

    public Bubble(Main plugin)
    {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
    {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this.plugin);
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bubble"))
        {
            if (sender instanceof Player)
            {
                if (args.length > 0 && args.length <= 2)
                {
                    if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]) != null)
                    {
                        Player victim = (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]));



            FixedMetadataValue metadataValue = new FixedMetadataValue(this.plugin, true);
            if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("off")){

                  Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + victim.getName() + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " Is no longer in a bubble!");
                victim.removeMetadata("isInbubble", this.plugin);

                return true;
            }else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("on")){

                  Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + victim.getName() + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " Is now in a bubble!");
                victim.setMetadata("isInBubble", metadataValue);

                if (victim.hasMetadata("isInBubble"))
                {
                    victim.sendMessage("Metadata assigned");
                }
                return true;
            }






        }
        else
        {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player is not online!");
            return false;
        }

        }
        else
        {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid arguments!");
            return false;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "The console cannot bubble someone!");
        return false;
    }

}



return false;
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
         Player mover = e.getPlayer();
         Location from = e.getFrom();
         Location to = e.getTo();
         Collection<Entity> nearbyEntities = mover.getWorld().
         getNearbyEntities(from,  10, 10, 10);//Get entities in a 10 block square from loc "from"
         List<Player> nearbyPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
         for (Entity en : nearbyEntities) {
             if (en instanceof Player)
             {
               nearbyPlayers.add((Player) en);
             }
         }
         for (Player victim : nearbyPlayers) {
             if (victim.hasMetadata("isInBubble") && victim != mover) {
                Location victimLoc = victim.getLocation();
                if (victimLoc.distance(to) <= 5) {//Radius 5
                    mover.sendMessage("mover");
                    victim.sendMessage("victim");
                     //Cancel so cant move
                     //we have nothing left no need to get in for statement again
                }
                }
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert bubble metadata to people so we know who is in bubble.

```
FixedMetadataValue metadataValue = new FixedMetadataValue(plugin, true);
victim.setMetadata("isInBubble", metadataValue);
```

Now you need to handle `PlayerMoveEvent` and get the players around the mover and check if any of these "isInBubble" like this (no need to check the value):

```
mover.hasMetadata("isInBubble");
```

To remove it you need the same plugin class that you created it with.

```
mover.removeMetadata("isInBubble", plugin);
```

I wrote this code for you:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
     Player mover = e.getPlayer();
     Location from = e.getFrom();
     Location to = e.getTo();
     Collection<Entity> nearbyEntities = mover.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(from,  10, 10, 10);//Get entities in a 10 block square from loc "from"
     List<Player> nearbyPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
     for (Entity en : nearbyEntities) {
         if (en instanceof Player)
           nearbyPlayers.add((Player) en);
     }
     for (Player victim : nearbyPlayers) {
         if (victim.hasMetadata("isInBubble") && victim != mover) {
            Location victimLoc = victim.getLocation();
            if (victimLoc.distance(to) <= 5) {//Radius 5
                e.setCancelled(true); //Cancel so cant move
                return; //we have nothing left no need to get in for statement again
            }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

You can use metadata to set and get radius.
Pay attention to `@EventHandler`.